# Mysql query returning the -help menu instead of query results

Tags: mysql, date-format

This is the query I am using in my shell script.
**mysql -h 'host' -p'pass' --skip-column-names  -e  "select date_format('due_date', "%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59") from table_name limit 5"**

When I run this I get the -help menu instead of query results. 
Is my syntax correct?

When I connect to Mysql and run just the query like this:
**select date_format('due_date', "%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59") from table_name limit 5**

I get the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

> mysql -h -p --skip-column-names -e "select date_format('due_date',
>   "%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59") from table_name limit 5"

what does the -h stand for here?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the double quotes in your query. Try.

```
mysql -h 'host' -p'pass' --skip-column-names -e "select date_format('due_date', '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') from table_name limit 5"
```

Comment: Unable to Vote up since I don't have enough reputation but that is it! Thank you.